# Datagridview is not Loading

Tags: error-handling, gridview, c#-3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIumV.png)
What should I do?

I was attaching dataset to my Gridview but it doesn't load and I can't see any tables on my Gridview!
I cant see any thing on my grid!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCcmS.png)
it is what I see!